# ggforce: geom_mark_ellipse - How to move connectors?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, ggforce

I have some data for which I would like to circle some different subsets. I am using `ggplot2` and `ggforce` to plot the data and draw an ellipse (`geom_mark_ellipse`) around the data.

I have an issue in that the positions of the connectors on the ellipses (for my data) are in ambiguous positions (at the conjunction of two ellipses, on the border of two ellipses that graze each other).

How can I manually set the position of the connector to the ellipse? Or at least influence them into a particular region?

I have some code below which captures the spirit in which I'm plotting my data. For the purpose of the example, how could I make all of the labels appear in the top left of the plot, or all join the ellipses at x == 0, -2, -4 for each of the factors?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)


x <- c(-1,0,1,-3,-2,2,3,-5,-4,4,5)
t <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)

tmp <- as_tibble_col(x, column_name = "x")
tmp <- tmp %>% mutate(t = t)

#How do I move the position of the label connectors on the ellipses?
tmp %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=x)) +
  geom_mark_ellipse(aes(label = t, group=t),con.cap = 0) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: [Looking at the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggforce/versions/0.3.1/topics/geom_mark_ellipse) for the `geom_mark_ellipse` function, it mentions the labels are dynamic and will move around if you resize.  In that case, there's not going to be a set way to do this via that function.  You would have to hide the labels and perhaps do this with a custom annotation... but it would be really tough to set the line position to connect to the ellipses.

Comment: @chemdork123 that's what I thought. When I get a chance, I might try making some fake data to go in the top left quadrant, and hide it. That should force everything to the bottom right.

Comment: Yeah, something tells me that going "wonky" is gonna be the only way to make this happen.  Know that the labels will move around when resizing if you use `geom_mark_ellipse`, so when plotting, then resize your window around and see what changes.

Comment: Well, my window is fixed, as I've go column widths for the figure to go into, so that is one variable I don't need to worry about.

Comment: Small things.  Good luck - feel free to post an answer to your own question if you indeed figure it out, as it would be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it for my contrived example, yet to try on my real data, but there is hope.

As shown in the code below, I created data to fill the area (top left) that I didn't want to have labels in, and gave it a factor of `""`. I manually set the colour of the connectors to `NA` for that factor, and got rid of the label background for everything. Because the factor is "", the label is an empty string, and nothing shows up. I also set `scale_colour_manual` to give the colour `NA` to the ellipse I didn't want to see.
I also filtered the `geom_point` to not show the data with a factor of `""`. Finally, I deleted the legend.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)

x <- c(-1,0,1,-3,-2,2,3,-5,-4,4,5)
t <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)

tmp <- as_tibble_col(x, column_name = "x")
tmp <- tmp %>% mutate(y=x)
tmp <- tmp %>% mutate(t = t)

#now lets add some dodging data
tmp <- tmp %>% mutate(t = as.character(t))
tmp <- tmp %>% add_row(x=c(-5,2.5,-2.5), y=c(-2.5,5,2.5),t="")

tmp %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_mark_ellipse(aes(label = t, group=t, colour=factor(t)),
                    con.cap = 0, con.colour = c(NA, "black","black","black"),
                    label.fill=NA) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c(NA, "black", "black", "black")) +
  geom_point(data = subset(tmp, t != "")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>